# Ng-options doesn't let me select options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I will try to explain.

I have a `<select>` with options loaded from ng-options in this way:

`<select ng-model="varModel" ng-options="v as k for (k, v) in variables"></select>`

So, this code displays a dropdown correctly, but when I try to select an option from the dropdown, it doesn't select the opction I clicked.

For example:

> Dropdown elements: Orange, Green, Red, White, Blue

I click in Green

> Blue is selected in the dropdown.

Thank you in advance, I hope the question be clear.

Comment: what does the variables object contain?

Comment: with "v as k for (k, v)" you display only the KEY inside the dropdown. If you want to know the value of the <select> just try to make an alert(varModel) inside the controller.

Comment: "it doesn't select the option I clicked": as you described the problem, it seems a browser problem. Try with another one